# I want to test to my controller method which consume=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE only

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, mockmvc, springmockito

I am using mockMvc for testing. How I can send PaymentOrderDto object value in mockMVc.perform which I can receive at controller method.

Like  PaymentOrderDto.setMid("m1") etc.

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public ResponseEntity<String> createPaymentOrder(HttpServletRequest request, PaymentOrderDto paymentOrderDto,
                                                     @RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile paymentReceiptFile,
                                                     @RequestParam(value = "contactId", required = true) String contactId,
                                                     HttpServletResponse response) {
                        
--method  body                           

}

List item
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as follows;

Controller endpoint;

```
@PostMapping(value = "createPaymentOrder", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> createPaymentOrder(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                 @RequestPart PaymentOrderDto paymentOrderDto,
                                                 @RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile paymentReceiptFile,
                                                 @RequestParam(value = "contactId", required = true) String contactId,
                                                 HttpServletResponse response) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(contactId + ":" + paymentOrderDto.getMid(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Test function;

```
@Test
void testMe() throws Exception {
    MockMultipartFile employeeJson = new MockMultipartFile("paymentOrderDto", null,
            "application/json", "{\"mid\": \"10\"}".getBytes());
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/createPaymentOrder")
            .file(employeeJson)
            //.file("") --> paymentReceiptFile which is not mandatory
            .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json"))
            .param("contactId", "C1")
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(mvcResult -> "C1:10".equals(mvcResult));
}
```